# She still isn't feeling very well / still doesn't feel very well

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

I came across the following sentences:

> Amanda broke her leg last week. She still isn't feeling very well.
>
> Amanda broke her leg last week. She still doesn't feel very well.

Can you tell which one is correct? Or are both of them correct, just with a difference in meaning?

Thanks!

Comment: Both are correct and idiomatic and they mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: In this case, they mean the same thing. (In certain contexts, however, they might not.)

Comment: In Britain, we tend to use use "feeling unwell" to describe a general feeling, often internal. One might feel unwell because of food poisoning or flu, or some other infectious disease; conversely one might feel perfectly well, (but in pain) with a broken leg.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I have the same impression as a native AmE speaker.  If you told me that someone "wasn't feeling very well" after a broken leg, I'd almost expect that they were having a bad reaction to the painkillers they were taking or something like that.